# java GC old generation is filling fast

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I'm having a problem that my GC (major) is running every few hours as my a lot of objects are going from young generation to old generation.
 
Can somebody please analyze and suggest what parameter i should be change to tune my GC?
My GC config params:
`-Xms6144M -Xmx6144M -Xloggc:gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=128K -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/usr/local/heapdump -XX:SurvivorRatio=4`
Below are the GC charts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are experiencing a full GC cycle on the old space every ~4h while running ParallelOldGC (you are on an old pre-Java-8 JVM judging by `-XX:MaxPermSize`). That doesn't look like a problem. What are you trying to optimize, full GC duration or trying to decrease memory usage?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah I would like to decrease the frequency of full GC as it is taking a lot of time.

Comment: By most standards the full GC is running quite rarely considering you're using the parallel collector. As the others mentioned this seems like it is an XY problem. Major collections are not the concern, pause times are.

Comment: yeah you may be right. I'm actually having problem understanding so big pause due to full GC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is the duration of the the full GC you can switch to a concurrent collector (e.g. CMS with `-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`) and hope that the full GC will be less frequent. The other approach would be to decrease the overall heap size as full GC duration is usually proportional to the size of the heap. You are experiencing a full GC every 4 hours, if you experience it once per hour but for quarter of the duration it might be worth doing.

You can try decrease number of live objects moving from New Space to Old Space by increasing the NewSize (e.g. directly using `-XX:NewSize=3g -XX:MaxNewSize=3g`). However only you know what your application is doing and what are the allocation patterns and the current 2g is generous.

Updating to newer JVM could help as as well e.g. as part of Java 10 G1 was fully parallelized (JEP 307). There is a good article on [Tuning Espresso’s JVM Performance](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/01/tuning_espresso_jvm) which compares CMS to G1.

Comment: And if nothing else helps, and you really see a "business" problem here - consider using the Azuul VM. That thing goes pauseless (they say).